# Boot up USB error

Tags: boot, usb

During initial boot up I get an error on several USB ports. The error is -32. I am using a Gigabyte GA-970A-D3P motherboard. I bought this used so I am not sure of its history but it has an FX-4300 CPU and all USB 2.0 ports are dead. If I plug a mouse into any the LED on the bottom is off. I assume the port has no 5V power but I can't get any technical info from Gigabyte: just the usual run-around. I saw some posts about problems with the 970 chips, the AMD SB950 specifically but is was not clear to me what the solution was. I have not yet tried all of the ideas presented in that series. I have 2 USB 3.0 ports and they appear to work. I would like to know what a -32 error means. It would also be nice to know how to identify the meaning of all Linux error codes. Thanks

Comment: Internet search engines. Search for "USB error -32".

Answer (score 2):

Thanks I used the link to see the error codes. I read some other posts about this error on a GA-970A board that suggested I add boot parameters to the Linux command line of "amd_iommu=on iommu=on" and this stopped my USB problems.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/driver-api/usb/error-codes.html

It's a `EPIPE 32` error which just means 'broken pipe'.

You can check such errors with 'errno' program, like this:
`errno 32`
which is a part of `moreutils` package.